# Finding the angles for the X, Y and Z axis in 3D - OpenGL/C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation, angle

I am currently trying to use OpenGL (With SDL) to draw a cube to the location where I left click in the screen and then get it to point at the position in the screen where I right click.

I can successfully draw a cube at my desired location using gluUnproject - Meaning I already know the coordinates of which my cube is situated.

However I do not know how to calculate all of the angles required to make my cube point at the new location.

Of course I am still using gluUnproject to find the coordinates of my right click, but I only know how to rotate around the Z axis from using 2D graphics.

For example before, if I wanted to rotate a quad around the Z axis (Of course, this would be a top down view where the Z axis is still "going through" the screen) in 2D I would do something like:

```
angle = atan2(mouseCoordsY - quadPosY, mouseCoordsX - quadPosX);
glRotatef(angle*180/PI, 0, 0, 1);
```

My question is, how would I go about doing this in 3D?

- Do I need to calculate the angles for each axis as I did above?
- If so how do I calculate the angle for rotation around the X and Y axis?
- If not, what method should I use to achieve my desired results?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you specify the z-coordinate represented by each mouse click? If you just set both to 0, then 2D geometry suffices, and I'm guessing that's not your intent.

Comment: A click in a 3d space should define a ray, not a point. I am curious to know how you achieved locating the cube in the first place.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Forgive me if I have mis-understood your question, but I am new to this and so although I think I know what you are asking for, I may still have the wrong idea. Basically if my cube is at (100, 200, 300) and I click at (400, 500, 600), I need to find the angles at which I need to rotate the cube, to get it to look at the second set of coordinates.

Comment: @tafa: I used gluUnProject to get the coordinates to use in glTranslatef(). To get the Z I used glReadPixels() as follows:
glReadPixels(mouseX, realY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, depth); Where depth is a GLfloat depth[2]; Then I used: gluUnProject((GLdouble) mouseX, (GLdouble) realY, depth[0], mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport, &wx, &wy, &wz); Using wx, wy and wz as my coordinates. But as I said in my previous comment I am new to this, so I am aware I could be doing things very very wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your cube is at A = (x0,y0,z0)

If your cube is currently looking at B=(x1,y1,z1)

and if you want it to look at C=(x2,y2,z2) then;

let v1 be the vector from A to B

v1 = B - A

and v2 be the one from A to C

v2 = C - A

First normalize them.

```
v1 = v1 / |v1|
v2 = v2 / |v2|
```

then calculate the rotation angle and the rotation axis as

```
angle = acos(v1*v2) //dot product
axis = v1 X v2 //cross product
```

You can call glRotate with

```
glRotate(angle, axis[0], axis[1], axis[2])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer tafa! I have been searching for tutorials and other resources on the matter for the past couple of days, and has tested stuff with dot products etc, but since I have only just come from 2D it wasn't making a lot of sense to me. But your answer has explained everything I needed to know in a very clear way, that none of the resources I found on google could. Thank you.

Comment: @Sour Lemon, glad to hear that.