# Angle between 3 vectors in 3d space

Tags: javascript, vector, 3d

As per the solution(s) in this post [Angle between 3 points in 3d space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729831/angle-between-3-points-in-3d-space) I have a java script function that takes 3 vectors(not just points/coords technically) & calculates the angles between them. Or rather not just between them individually but between each as if each is a vertex on a surface. The function's uses its 2nd argument to calculate the angle between the other two(1 & 3). I run the function 3 times with 3 different orders of the input vectors to get 3 angles & it works fine. I'll show it usage soon. In the program I'm using the function in, the input vecs are just positions on the surface of a sphere that I can position anywhere on it with lat/lon sliders, which I connect by lines(arcs actually) that creates a spherical triangle wherever I position the vecs(as like vertexes of the triangle. Anyway, that was just some background info so its clear. So, even though the function in question its a 3D solution, apparently it assumes the vectors are all co-planar, which they are not. It finds the angles of each vertex & the 3 angles obtained always just add up to 180 deg. But on a sphere, it should always be at least 180 & upto just under 540(pretty sure). I need the excess. So, I think I just have to get the function to take into account that the input vectors z components are what is the normal to sphere's surface & their x & y components are what can form a tangent plane, which they are, as I also use them to position a 2D circle of any radius anywhere on the sphere. Here is the function:

```
function ang3D2(v1, v2, v3) {
      // Copy and normalize the input vectors
      let V1 = v1.copy().normalize();
      let V2 = v2.copy().normalize();
      let V3 = v3.copy().normalize();
  
      let Va = p5.Vector.sub(V1,V2).normalize();
      let Vb = p5.Vector.sub(V3,V2).normalize();
  
      let dots = p5.Vector.dot(Va,Vb);
  
      let crosses = p5.Vector.cross(Va,Vb);
      let crossesMag = crosses.mag();// / V2.z; ?
  
      let angle = (Math.acos(dots) * 180.0) / Math.PI; 
      //let angle2 = (Math.atan2(crossesMag,dots) * 180.0) / Math.PI;
  
      return Math.round(angle * 1000) / 1000; // here I'm just changing //between returning acos(angle) & atan(angle2) to test. angle2 seems //close its just that the "1st" angle is wrong. acos(angle) is what //works for coplanar

    }//ang3d2()  

    //based off of //https://gist.github.com/andfaulkner/c4ad12a72d29bcd653eb4b8cca2ae476 

    //& its usage:

    function angs() {
      if (cyl1V && cyl2V && cyl3V) {
        //let angs;
        ang1 = ang3D2(cyl2V, cyl1V, cyl3V);
        ang2 = ang3D2(cyl1V, cyl2V, cyl3V);
        ang3 = ang3D2(cyl1V, cyl3V, cyl2V);
        angS = ang1 + ang2 + ang3;
        console.log(angS);
      } //fi
    } //angs
```

So, the function works as it is(almost in the way I need it to) but, in my case the input vecs are NOT coplanar(though it is a 3D solution?!). & I hope its clear as to what I've been trying. Using atan(cross product) instead of just acos(dot) etc. Can anyone PLEASE steer me in the right direction ? For some reason I can't find much info about this in particular yet I'm sure its probably on the trivial side, though I'm not a professional programmer by any means. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the original Q over a month ago & got no responses. So, after quite a few very long nights I finally got a solution. I turns out that the "triple product"(like a cross of the cross products) is your friend in this case. The useage is the same as above. Perhaps I just worded the Q poorly. But am sharing the solution just in case it helps anyone in the future.

```
  function ang3D(v1, v2, v3) {
  //call in 3 different orders middle v2 is main ref
  // 1st copy and normalize the input vectors even though we'll try to use 
  //static methods
  let V1 = v1.copy().normalize();
  let V2 = v2.copy().normalize();
  let V3 = v3.copy().normalize();

  //sub 1 from 2 then 3 from 2 to get main working triangle vertex vecs
  let Va = p5.Vector.sub(V1, V2).normalize(); //for acos
  let Vb = p5.Vector.sub(V3, V2).normalize(); //not mormed if atan

  //1st cross
  let cross = p5.Vector.cross(Va, Vb);

  //get the cross of the crosses
  let a = p5.Vector.cross(Va, V2);
  let b = p5.Vector.cross(Vb, V2);

  // & the dot & mags a&b;
  let dot = p5.Vector.dot(a, b);
  let mag = a.mag() * b.mag();

  let ang = (Math.acos(dot / mag) * 180.0) / Math.PI;

  return Math.round(ang * 1000) / 1000;
} //ang3d2()
```